# VS2017 Missing namespaces (after git pull)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a `Visual Studio Solution` (multiple projects) which was able to build on another computer in the past, that can't build after being pulled with `Git` on a new computer. The `IDE` (VS2017), `platform target` (Any CPU), `.Net Framework` (.Net 4.6.1), ... and everything else should be the same, yet it gives a few "`The type or namespace name 'nameOfTypeOrNamespace' does not exist in the namespace`" errors. There're also a few "`Metadata file 'pathToFile.dll" could not be found`" errors. Example screenshot:

[image: Imgur]

Most of the missing assembly's are self-written but there are a few which are thrid party, as seen in the solution explorer. I also don't seem to have a reference folder in the solution anymore:

[image: Imgur]

I know there's already a few questions involving missing namespaces, but none seem to match my particular case. I've already checked references and namespaces but can't seem to find the problem (no typo's eithersince it worked before). It's probably really hard for someone to find the problem without the project, *which I can't share*, so my question:
**How should one best search for the solution?**

I've also checked my `.gitignore` file and verified that it shouldn't have caused this issue.
**Update** as said in the comment section: I'm using `Nuget` but the `Restore Nuget Packages` option does not work out.

Comment: Are you using Nuget? If so, does a package restore fix it?

Comment: I am using Nuget yes, should've mentioned that in the main post. However, using the Restore Nuget Packages option doesn't seem to do it. Not for the custom or third party ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently solved this issue by doing the following:

1. Remove `packages` from the `.gitignore`-file
2. Open a cmd and type the following Git commando's (be sure to commit all your changes first since you might lose them by executing following commands):

   a. `git rm -r --cached .` (clears the cache so that Git can detect changes)
   b. `git add .` (adds all changed files)
   c. `git commit -m "Fixing the packages issue"` (commit the changes)

Keep in mind that this is only a quick fix or a hack and that this doesn't actually solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

@Wouter's solution is working but as he said it's not optimal way and cause huge amount of source control storage occupied as well as increase download and upload size in push and pull(Checkin and Checkout in TFS).

To restore packages if 'Restore Nuget Packages' not works, use this solution:

From Tools menu in Visual studio, chose *NuGet Package Manager--> Package Manager Console*
and run this command:

```
Update-Package –reinstall
```

I hope It works.